# Infinite sum bug

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, summation

Why:

```
Limit[Sum[Sqrt[-i^2 + n^2]/n^2, {i, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
(* 0 *)
```

but:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 1}]
(* Pi/4 *)
```

The former is the Riemann sum of the latter. They should be equal.

(Version: 11.3)

Comment: The limit expression you gave returns unevaluated in version 12.0 (Win10-64 desktop) and 13.0 (Linux cloud)

Comment: Please do not use the bugs tag for new questions; the tag can be added when the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug.

Comment: The limit expression is wrong, should be `Sum[Sqrt[1 - i^2/n^2]/n, {i, 1, Infinity}]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann:  Isn't that equivalent?$$\frac{\sqrt{1 - i^2/n^2}}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{n^2 - i^2}{n^2}} = \frac{1}{n^2} \sqrt{n^2 - i^2}$$

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 13.0.0 on Windows 10

```
AsymptoticSum[Sqrt[-i^2/n^2 + 1]/n, {i, 1, n}, n -> Infinity]
```

> `Pi/4`

It should be noticed that

```
AsymptoticSum[Sqrt[-i^2 + n^2]/n^2, {i, 1, n}, n -> Infinity]
```

returns the input.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my question.

Answer (score 5):

Numerically solving,

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

lim = NLimit[Sum[Sqrt[-i^2 + n^2]/n^2, {i, 1, n}], n -> Infinity, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* 0.785398 *)

RootApproximant[lim/Pi]*Pi

(* π/4 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my question.

Answer (score 4):

Try midpoint discretization `x=1/(2n)+i/n, i,1,n-1`:

```
dx = 1/n;
Sqrt[1 - x^2] dx  /. x -> dx/2 + i dx // FullSimplify (*Sqrt[1 - (1 + 2 i)^2/(4 n^2)]/n*)
```

Unfortunately Mathematica can't solve the limit

```
Limit[Sum[Sqrt[1 - (1 + 2 i)^2/(4 n^2)]/n , {i,1, n - 1}], n -> Infinity]
```

but numerically evaluation gives expected result `~Pi/4`

```
Table[{n,NSum[Sqrt[1 - (1 + 2 i)^2/(4 n^2)]/n, {i, 1, n -1}]}, {n, {10, 100,1000 , 10000}}]
(*{{10, 0.688228}, {100, 0.775482}, {1000,0.784401}, {10000, 0.785298}}*)
```

`left riemann sum` works too

```
Table[{n,NSum[Sqrt[1 - i^2/n^2]/n, {i, 0, n - 1}]},{n, {10, 100, 1000 ,10000}}]
(* {{10, 0.82613}, {100, 0.790104}, {1000, 0.785889}, {10000, 0.785448}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.